# Event for select a date on datePicker

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to compare two calendar dates. I wrote the javascript function too. But how can I execute this function(which event?) on select a date from the datePicker? See my JSF code

```
<h:outputText value="From Date" />
<p:calendar id="fDate" value="#{backingBean.fDate}" mode="popup"
    showOn="button" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">

</p:calendar>
<p:message id="fId" for="fDate" />

<h:outputText value="To Date" />
<p:calendar id="tDate" value="#{backingBean.tDate}" mode="popup"
    showOn="button" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" ondateselected="compareDate();" />
<p:message id="tId" for="tDate" />
```

`ondateselected="compareDate();` is not executing at all, it is wrong ,I guess. 
I'm using primefaces-3.0.M3 with JSF2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure when exactly they changed it to use p:ajax , but maybe it was before 3.0M3

so try this way

```
<p:calendar value="#{backingBean.tDate}">
    <p:ajax event=”dateSelect” oncomplete="compareDate();return false;" />
</p:calendar>
```

now when i think about it again i think you can put the js function in onsuccess="" and remove the return false;